AWS MWAA env getting struck when trying to use harshicorp as alternate secret backend
I have created the AWS MWAA version 2.9.2
I want to use harshicorp as alternate secret backend.
I have added:
secrets.backend=airflow.providers.hashicorp.secrets.vault.VaultBackend

secrets.backend_kwargs={"connections_path":"airflow/connections","url":"<vault_url>","mount_point":"<vault_mount_path>","token_path":"<vault_token>"}

Under airflow.cfg.
I have added the harshicorp plugin as well (apache-airflow-providers-hashicorp==3.7.1) .
When I update the env with this configuration, it every time gets struck in updating state for ~3 hours and in the end, fails with no proper errors specified.
